# 2 3D plots in one graph: changing colors and z bounds are ignored?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-3dplot, axis

I am trying to plot two 3D plots in one graph, but Latex stops recognizing the zmin and zmax values for some reason, so it doesn't compile because dimensions are too large. Reducing the number of samples did nothing to fix this.

I also don't know how to change the colors of one of the graphs, since the switch has to be made in the axis environment, and that is the same for both graphs. If I create a new axis environment, I can no longer create the legend. I had to turn the plots into meshes temporarily since that was the only way to make them different colors.

Any help? Thanks in advance!
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0.1, ymin=0.1, xmax=2.0, ymax=2.5, zmin=0, zmax=140, xlabel=$x_1$, ylabel=$x_2$, zlabel=$\sigma$, width=1\linewidth, view={-60}{20}, legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=center, legend columns=-1}]
         \addplot3[mesh,draw=red,samples=45] 
        {(44.5*1000 * (1 + x) * sqrt(1 + x^2)) / (2 * sqrt(2) * x * y * 6.452/10000) / 1000000}; % \sigma_1 in MPa
         \addplot3[mesh,draw=blue,samples=45] 
        {(44.5*1000 * (x - 1) * sqrt(1 + x^2)) / (2 * sqrt(2) * x * y * 6.452/10000) / 1000000}; % \sigma_2 in MPa
    \legend{$\sigma_1$,$\sigma_2$}
    \end{axis}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code misses an `\end{tikzpicture}`, and you want to also set appropriate domains to avoid the dimension too large errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0.1, ymin=0.1, xmax=2.0, ymax=2.5, zmin=0, zmax=140, xlabel=$x_1$, ylabel=$x_2$, zlabel=$\sigma$, width=1\linewidth, view={-60}{20}, 
        legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=center, legend columns=-1},
        samples=45,domain=0.1:2,domain y=0.1:2]
         \addplot3[mesh,draw=red] 
        {(44.5*1000 * (1 + x) * sqrt(1 + x^2)) / (2 * sqrt(2) * x * y * 6.452/10000) / 1000000}; % \sigma_1 in MPa
         \addplot3[mesh,draw=blue] 
        {(44.5*1000 * (x - 1) * sqrt(1 + x^2)) / (2 * sqrt(2) * x * y * 6.452/10000) / 1000000}; % \sigma_2 in MPa
    \legend{$\sigma_1$,$\sigma_2$}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.